# Is there a way to auto save the Terminal Commands in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to autosave the texts/commands/output in the Terminal window of Visual Studio Code
thereby I can re-use them.

Thanks,
JG

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deepakgupta191199.save-commands